# For an Excel Formula's variable taking a Range, input row number by the result of a formula

Tags: excel, dynamic, reference, formula

I'm trying to fill in this =SERIES function to populate a line plot in Excel 2007.

```
=SERIES($BB$1,$BB$2:$BB$16,$BC$2:$BC$16,1)
```

Now the range $BB$2:$BB$16 and the one that follows are set for illustration. However, my plot needs to find a new range each time dynamically since the number of data points my function returns are different each time.

I can get the number of data points with a =COUNTA(BB2:BB1000), then I can chuck this number (plus 1 to make reference right) into the spot where 16 is in this case. How would I reference the following string as a range?

> ="$BB$2:$BB$" & COUNTA(BB2:BB1000)

In the place of

=SERIES([Cell],[Range],[Range]...)

If I just input this Excel won't take it. I tried INDIRECT but it returns the value of a cell, and can't be used as a range

Comment: I just found something online using OFFSET with named ranges. Is there a more straight forward way?

Comment: are you trying to use the `SERIESSUM` formula? I don't think the `SERIES` formula exists in excel? is it an add on or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `INDEX` to specify the range

```
$BB$2:INDEX($BB:$BB,COUNTA($BB:$BB)+1)
```

While it can also be done with `OFFSET` or `INDIRECT` they are both volitile, so using `INDEX` is better because its not volitile.

For completness:
Using `OFFSET`

```
OFFSET($BB$2,0,0,COUNTA($BB:$BB))
```

Using `INDIRECT`

```
$BB$2:INDIRECT("BB"&COUNTA($BB:$BB)+1)
```

While these all work for "normal" cell formulas, it seems they don't work directly in a chart `SERIES` formula.  However, they can still be used by creating a **Worksheet scoped named range**, and using *that* in the `SERIES` formula.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the INDIRECT function:)

say you have three cell that can dynamically calculate the address of your input range.
something like what you suggested and it is in the cell A1

```
="$BB$2:$BB$" & COUNTA(BB2:BB1000) ---> in cell A1
```

You can use the Indirect function like this:

```
=SERIES(INDIRECT(A1),[RANGE],[RANGE])
```

Hope this helps!